# Set focus on particular tab in IE and/or FireFox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, bho, hook

I want to write an application that will monitor the content of all open tabs in IE / FireFox and trigger event once particular data is displayed in the tab.

I would like to know if there is an API for IE/FF to set focus on particular TAB, so that once  event is triggered I set focus on a relevant tab.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no specific API to activate tab or set focus to it.

Bellow is an code how you can activate tab, but it is only IE specific!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Accessibility;

namespace IETabsInteraction
{
    internal class TabActivator
    {
        #region Nested type: OBJID

        private enum OBJID : uint
        {
            OBJID_WINDOW = 0x00000000,
        }

        #endregion

        #region Declarations

        private const int CHILDID_SELF = 0;
        private readonly IntPtr _hWnd;
        private IAccessible _accessible;

        [DllImport("oleacc.dll")]
        private static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint id, ref Guid iid,
                                                             [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] ref object
                                                                 ppvObject);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass,
                                                  string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("oleacc.dll")]
        private static extern int AccessibleChildren(IAccessible paccContainer, int iChildStart, int cChildren,
                                                     [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] object[] rgvarChildren, out int pcObtained);

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        internal TabActivator(IntPtr ieHandle)
        {
            _hWnd = ieHandle;
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref _accessible);

            CheckForAccessible();
        }

        private TabActivator(IAccessible acc)
        {
            if (acc == null)
                throw new Exception("Could not get accessible");

            _accessible = acc;
        }

        #endregion

        private TabActivator[] Children
        {
            get
            {
                var num = 0;
                var res = GetAccessibleChildren(_accessible, out num);

                if (res == null)
                    return new TabActivator[0];

                var list = new List<TabActivator>(res.Length);

                foreach (object obj in res)
                {
                    var acc = obj as IAccessible;

                    if (acc != null)
                        list.Add(new TabActivator(acc));
                }

                return list.ToArray();
            }
        }

        private int ChildCount
        {
            get { return _accessible.accChildCount; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets LocationUrl of the tab
        /// </summary>
        private string LocationUrl
        {
            get
            {
                var url = _accessible.accDescription[CHILDID_SELF];

                if (url.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
                    url = url.Split('\n')[1];

                return url;
            }
        }

        private void CheckForAccessible()
        {
            if (_accessible == null)
                throw new Exception("Could not get accessible.  Accessible can't be null");
        }

        internal void ActivateByTabsUrl(string tabsUrl)
        {
            var tabIndexToActivate = GetTabIndexToActivate(tabsUrl);

            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(_hWnd), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref _accessible);

            CheckForAccessible();

            var index = 0;
            var ieDirectUIHWND = new TabActivator(_hWnd);

            foreach (var accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
            {
                foreach (var child in accessor.Children)
                {
                    foreach (var tab in child.Children)
                    {
                        if (tabIndexToActivate >= child.ChildCount - 1)
                            return;

                        if (index == tabIndexToActivate)
                        {
                            tab.ActivateTab();
                            return;
                        }

                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void ActivateTab()
        {
            _accessible.accDoDefaultAction(CHILDID_SELF);
        }

        private int GetTabIndexToActivate(string tabsUrl)
        {
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(_hWnd), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref _accessible);

            CheckForAccessible();

            var index = 0;
            var ieDirectUIHWND = new TabActivator(_hWnd);

            foreach (var accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
            {
                foreach (var child in accessor.Children)
                {
                    foreach (var tab in child.Children)
                    {
                        var tabUrl = tab.LocationUrl;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tabUrl))
                        {
                            if (tab.LocationUrl.Contains(tabsUrl))
                                return index;
                        }

                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }

        private IntPtr GetDirectUIHWND(IntPtr ieFrame)
        {
            // For IE 8:
            var directUI = FindWindowEx(ieFrame, IntPtr.Zero, "CommandBarClass", null);
            directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", null);
            directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "TabBandClass", null);
            directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "DirectUIHWND", null);

            if (directUI == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // For IE 9:
                //directUI = FindWindowEx(ieFrame, IntPtr.Zero, "WorkerW", "Navigation Bar");
                directUI = FindWindowEx(ieFrame, IntPtr.Zero, "WorkerW", null);
                directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", null);
                directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "TabBandClass", null);
                directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "DirectUIHWND", null);
            }

            return directUI;
        }

        private static int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, OBJID idObject, ref IAccessible acc)
        {
            var guid = new Guid("{618736e0-3c3d-11cf-810c-00aa00389b71}"); // IAccessibleobject obj = null;
            object obj = null;

            var num = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, (uint) idObject, ref guid, ref obj);

            acc = (IAccessible) obj;

            return num;
        }

        private static object[] GetAccessibleChildren(IAccessible ao, out int childs)
        {
            childs = 0;
            object[] ret = null;
            var count = ao.accChildCount;

            if (count > 0)
            {
                ret = new object[count];
                AccessibleChildren(ao, 0, count, ret, out childs);
            }

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, a lot of lines for such a simple task :)

In order to execute it you will need:

```
var ie = new ShellWindows();

// check if ie is open and get first tab of the ie
if (ie.Count > 0)
{    
    var hWnd = (IntPtr)ie.Item(0).HWND;
    new TabActivator(hWnd).ActivateByTabsUrl("www.stackoverflow.com");
}
```

This code sets focus to the tab with specific URL, but you can change it to activate tab with specific title, etc.

Comment: I know this is a bit old question, but I found Your answer with google. I try to implement it for IE8 & IE9, but I get error in `LocationURL` in line `var url = _accessible.accDescription[CHILDID_SELF];`. Error says `Property, indexer, or event 'accDescription' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor method 'Accessibility.IAccessible.get_accDescription(object)`. I'm using .NET 3.5 this may be the problem? Can this be fixed? I really would like to use Your solution :)

Comment: This appears to be the only way to activate a tab.  In my experience if the user has turned off tab browsing in IE, then this code somehow gets "stuck" but eventually throws the error.  I now first check in the registry if tab browsing is turned on before using this.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to write an add on.

Tabs look like windows to content so you can use a regular DOM Window object to discover some info about the current tab and do some things - close(), focus(), resizeTo() etc. Problem is Firefox and other modern browser suppress or ignore some of these events due to the default popup blocking behaviour. In addition, content cannot tell how many tabs are open, or what's running in them for security reasons so there would be no way to poll them for example. Best that you can do is is call window.opener from one window to find out which other one opened it.

The only way you're going to get full level of access is by writing an add-on. Every browser has its own way of writing add ons, some of which will be easier to write than others.