# Javascript - How to make a browser switch tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code a timed event launches a ModalDialog. If the user switches tabs before the event the tab blinks but that is it.

Is there a way to make the browser switch to the tab the dialog is on?

Thank you

Cheers for all your advice. I should of said before but code will only be run through IE and the users are not allowed to alter any settings.

Comment: The answer give here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753907/set-focus-on-particular-tab-in-ie-and-or-firefox applies to your case as well.. you'll have to write IE add-on to achieve such thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a cross-browser way do focus a tab/window that's 100% reliable, especially in newer browsers.  This would be an advertisers dream...so it's **actively blocked** in most newer browsers.

As a user, I'm glad it's difficult in most cases, impossible in others to do this.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reliable way to do that. The Internet Explorers are the most cooperative about raising windows (which is what switching tabs amounts to), while Safari pretty much ignores all such requests. Firefox can be configured (by its user, not by your code) to allow windows to grab focus, but it's rare for anybody to do that.

You can have your code call `window.focus()` but don't rely on it to work.

Comment: Pointy is correct. You simply can't achieve this in a graceful manner and only IE will be helpful. Besides, as a user it's particularly frustrating, so before you know it your users will be using the browser to block the action anyway.