# How to highlight a browser tab with color

Tags: jquery

I have a chat web application and I need a feature wherein if a particular user has multiple tabs open in the browser window and if the chat tab isnt the active one, in case if he receives a ping from the other end, the chat tab should automatically highlight to grab the users attention.

I am planning to do this in jQuery. Any idea how this could be achieved. I know we could use the .focus and .blur method to catch the tab active/inactive status but how to make the tab blip with color when the browser is minimized.

Comment: Could you please made a demo on jsFiddle.net. Are you using custom tabs, or jQuery UI? Are you talking about the actual browser tab, or a tab on a page?

Comment: @fudgey talking abt actual browser tab

Comment: Ahhh, ok I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the actual browser functionality with jQuery because the web content is isolated, or sandboxed, from the actual browser for security reasons.

If you really want something that will work you'll have to make a browser addon, which would then need to be downloaded and enabled by the user.

Check out [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123950/javascript-how-to-make-a-browser-switch-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

You could throw up an alert or confirm box, but that would get really annoying. Maybe you could use different sounds to alert the user of different windows...

Your best bet would be to keep it all on the same page and create tabs on your page.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

You could then do whatever you wanted to alert the user.