# Close the current tab of browser and go to the parent tab on a click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I want to close the current focused tab of browser and return/focus to its parent tab.

//HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">Go back</a>
```

//JavaScript code:

```
<script>
function close_window() {
        if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
        close();
       //code to focus the parent tab
      }
    }
</script>
```

Please do help.

Comment: It is not working I'm guessing? What errors do you get? Did you open the tab (that you want to close) via JavaScript?

Comment: i suggest you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4123994/2922310)

Comment: Putvande, Form the parent=(1) tab I'm opening the new=(2) tab (which I want to close and return to (1) tab.), then in the (2) tab when I click the link the (2) tab should close and (1) tab should open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is any specific workaround for this which is 100% reliable. You can close the current browser like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close</a>
```

but there is no way through which you can set the focus back on parent window reliably

You may refer this: [Bug 105722 - Closing tabs should return to 'parent' tab.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105722)