# How to bring focus to a tab in IE8?

Tags: c#

I am working on a project in C# where I have to enable tab browsing in IE8. Up to now I can open a browser, open tabs and navigate the tabs. However, I can not bring focus to the tab I am working with. Any ideas about how to do this will be more than welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us what mechanism you are using to automate IE?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set focus on particular tab in IE and/or FireFox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753907/set-focus-on-particular-tab-in-ie-and-or-firefox)

Comment: David, I am using COM Objects.

Answer (score 1):

The original post: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/03a8c835-e9e4-405b-8345-6c3d36bc8941

My code:

```
using Accessibility;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ADDIProtocol
{
    publicclass IEAccessible
    {
        privateenum OBJID : uint
        {
            OBJID_WINDOW = 0x00000000,
        }

        privateconstint IE_ACTIVE_TAB = 2097154;
        privateconstint CHILDID_SELF = 0;
        private IAccessible accessible;

        private IEAccessible[] Children
        {
            get
            {
                int num = 0;
                object[] res = GetAccessibleChildren(accessible, out num);

                if (res == null) returnnew IEAccessible[0];

                List<IEAccessible> list = new List<IEAccessible>(res.Length);

                foreach (object obj in res)
                {
                    IAccessible acc = obj as IAccessible;

                    if (acc != null) list.Add(new IEAccessible(acc));
                }

                return list.ToArray();
            }
        }

        privatestring Name
        {
            get
            {
                return accessible.get_accName(CHILDID_SELF);
            }
        }

        privateint ChildCount
        {
            get
            {
                return accessible.accChildCount;
            }
        }

        public IEAccessible()
        { }

        public IEAccessible(IntPtr ieHandle, string tabCaptionToActivate)
        {
            int tabCount = GetTabCount(ieHandle);

            if (tabCount > 0)
            {
                AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref accessible);

                if (accessible == null) thrownew Exception();

                IEAccessible ieDirectUIHWND = new IEAccessible(ieHandle);

                foreach (IEAccessible accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
                {
                    foreach (IEAccessible child in accessor.Children)
                    {
                        foreach (IEAccessible tab  in child.Children)
                        {
                            if (tab.Name == tabCaptionToActivate)
                            {
                                tab.Activate();

                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public IEAccessible(IntPtr ieHandle, int tabIndexToActivate)
        {
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref accessible);

            if (accessible == null) thrownew Exception();

            int index = 0;
            IEAccessible ieDirectUIHWND = new IEAccessible(ieHandle);

            foreach (IEAccessible accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
            {
                foreach (IEAccessible child in accessor.Children)
                {
                    foreach (IEAccessible tab in child.Children)
                    {
                        if (tabIndexToActivate >= child.ChildCount - 1) return;

                        if (index == tabIndexToActivate)
                        {
                            tab.Activate();

                            return;
                        }

                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private IEAccessible(IntPtr ieHandle)
        {
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref accessible);

            if (accessible == null) thrownew Exception();
        }

        publicstring GetActiveTabUrl(IntPtr ieHandle)
        {
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref accessible);

            if (accessible == null) thrownew Exception();

            IEAccessible ieDirectUIHWND = new IEAccessible(ieHandle);

            foreach (IEAccessible accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
            {
                foreach (IEAccessible child in accessor.Children)
                {
                    foreach (IEAccessible tab in child.Children)
                    {
                        object tabIndex = tab.accessible.get_accState(CHILDID_SELF);

                        if ((int)tabIndex == IE_ACTIVE_TAB)
                        {
                            string description = tab.accessible.get_accDescription(CHILDID_SELF);

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
                            {
                                if (description.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
                                {
                                    string url = description.Substring(description.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine)).Trim();

                                    return url;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return String.Empty;
        }

        publicint GetActiveTabIndex(IntPtr ieHandle)
        {
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref accessible);

            if (accessible == null) thrownew Exception();

            int index = 0;
            IEAccessible ieDirectUIHWND = new IEAccessible(ieHandle);

            foreach (IEAccessible accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
            {
                foreach (IEAccessible child in accessor.Children)
                {
                    foreach (IEAccessible tab in child.Children)
                    {
                        object tabIndex = tab.accessible.get_accState(0);

                        if ((int)tabIndex == IE_ACTIVE_TAB) return index;

                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }

        publicstring GetActiveTabCaption(IntPtr ieHandle)
        {
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref accessible);

            if (accessible == null) thrownew Exception();

            IEAccessible ieDirectUIHWND = new IEAccessible(ieHandle);

            foreach (IEAccessible accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
            {
                foreach (IEAccessible child in accessor.Children)
                {
                    foreach (IEAccessible tab in child.Children)
                    {
                        object tabIndex = tab.accessible.get_accState(0);


                        if ((int)tabIndex == IE_ACTIVE_TAB) return tab.Name;
                    }
                }
            }

            return String.Empty;
        }

        public List<string> GetTabCaptions(IntPtr ieHandle)
        {
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref accessible);

            if (accessible == null) thrownew Exception();

            IEAccessible ieDirectUIHWND = new IEAccessible(ieHandle);
            List<string> captionList = new List<string>();

            foreach (IEAccessible accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
            {
                foreach (IEAccessible child in accessor.Children)
                    foreach (IEAccessible tab in child.Children) captionList.Add(tab.Name);
            }

            if (captionList.Count > 0) captionList.RemoveAt(captionList.Count - 1);

            return captionList;
        }

        publicint GetTabCount(IntPtr ieHandle)
        {
            AccessibleObjectFromWindow(GetDirectUIHWND(ieHandle), OBJID.OBJID_WINDOW, ref accessible);

            if (accessible == null) return 0; // throw new Exception();

            IEAccessible ieDirectUIHWND = new IEAccessible(ieHandle);

            foreach (IEAccessible accessor in ieDirectUIHWND.Children)
            {
                foreach (IEAccessible child in accessor.Children)
                {
                    foreach (IEAccessible tab in child.Children) return child.ChildCount - 1;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private IntPtr GetDirectUIHWND(IntPtr ieFrame)
        {
            IntPtr directUI = FindWindowEx(ieFrame, IntPtr.Zero, "CommandBarClass", null);
            directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", null);
            directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "TabBandClass", null);
            directUI = FindWindowEx(directUI, IntPtr.Zero, "DirectUIHWND", null);

            return directUI;
        }

        private IEAccessible(IAccessible acc)
        {
            if (acc == null) thrownew Exception();

            accessible = acc;
        }

        privatevoid Activate()
        {
            accessible.accDoDefaultAction(CHILDID_SELF);
        }

        privatestaticobject[] GetAccessibleChildren(IAccessible ao, outint childs)
        {
            childs = 0;
            object[] ret = null;
            int count = ao.accChildCount;

            if (count > 0)
            {
                ret = newobject[count];
                AccessibleChildren(ao, 0, count, ret, out childs);
            }

            return ret;
        }

        #region Interop
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        privatestaticextern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        privatestaticint AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, OBJID idObject, ref IAccessible acc)
        {
            Guid guid = new Guid("{618736e0-3c3d-11cf-810c-00aa00389b71}"); // IAccessibleobject obj = null;
            int num = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, (uint)idObject, ref guid, ref obj);

            acc = (IAccessible)obj;

            return num;
        }

        [DllImport("oleacc.dll")]
        private static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint id, ref Guid iid, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] refobject ppvObject);

        [DllImport("oleacc.dll")]
        private static extern int AccessibleChildren(IAccessible paccContainer, int iChildStart, int cChildren, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] object[] rgvarChildren, outint pcObtained);
        #endregion
    }
}
```